How to execute a DAG of tasks using async.io?
I have written the following code:
`
    async def execute_task(self, task_id):
        await self.tasks[task_id]()
        self.task_status[task_id] = "done"

        async with self.lock:
            for successor in self.dag.successors(task_id):
                if all(self.task_status[predecessor] == "done" for predecessor in self.dag.predecessors(successor)):
                    self.ready_queue.append(successor)

    async def execute_dag(self):
        for task in self.dag.nodes:
            if self.dag.in_degree(task) == 0:
                self.ready_queue.append(task)
        
        

        while self.ready_queue:
            current_tasks = []
            async with self.lock:
                while self.ready_queue:
                    task_id = self.ready_queue.popleft()
                    self.task_status[task_id] = "running"
                    current_tasks.append(self.execute_task(task_id))
            
            await asyncio.gather(*current_tasks)


For the following testcase:
1 => 2
1 => 5
2 => 3
3 => 4
5 => 4

I have the output:
Executing Task 1
Task 1 Done
Executing Task 2
Executing Task 5
Task 2 Done
Task 5 Done
Executing Task 3
Task 3 Done
Executing Task 4
Task 4 Done

Where the task 5 takes significantly more time. Here, why does task 3 wait for task 5 to complete? asyncio.gather seems to run the tasks in batches. Is there any workaround for this?
I want a minimal code to execute tasks in parallel. But a few testcases seem to bottleneck in my implementation.

see, the problem is each time asyncio.gather is called, only the tasks in current_tasks are executed and the remaining workflow blocks. I want to modify this code such that it works in parallel whenever posiible. i.e., instaed of using gather, I want some mechanism where I can individually take care of processes and dependencies.

Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - and include your test data either hard coded in te script, or in a way the code can be run with it. WIthout knowing what is self.dag, and how the whole thing is " put in motion" (including instantiating the " hidden" class) it is hard to help here.

What you are observing is by design, since you await the tasks in batches. You could try to move the task start-up (check if all predecessors are done ...) into the execute part. Here's a very rudimentary example, with the graph from your test case (not integrated into your class framework, since it is mostly unknown):
from random import randrange
import asyncio


# Helper function for the creation of simple sample coroutine
def make_sample_coro(n):

    async def coro():
        print(f"Start of task {n} ...")
        await asyncio.sleep(randrange(1, 5))
        print(f"... End of task {n}")

    return coro


async def main():
    # Simple graph in standard representation (node => neighbours)
    graph = {1: {2, 5}, 2: {3}, 3: {4}, 4: set(), 5: {4}}
    tasks = {n: make_sample_coro(n) for n in graph}
    tasks_done = set()
    
    async def execute_task(ID):
        print(f"Trying to execute task {ID} ...")
        predecessors = {n for n, ns in graph.items() if ID in ns}
        while not predecessors <= tasks_done:  # Check if task can be started
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await tasks[ID]()
        tasks_done.add(ID)
    
    await asyncio.gather(*[execute_task(n) for n in graph])
    print("... Finished")


asyncio.run(main())

Example output (changes always due to the random part):
Trying to execute task 1 ...
Trying to execute task 2 ...
Trying to execute task 3 ...
Trying to execute task 4 ...
Trying to execute task 5 ...
Start of task 1 ...
... End of task 1
Start of task 2 ...
Start of task 5 ...
... End of task 2
Start of task 3 ...
... End of task 3
... End of task 5
Start of task 4 ...
... End of task 4
... Finished

In this run task 3 starts before task 5 is finished (doesn't necessarily have to be that way, in particular if task 5 is very fast).

Thanks for the answer! What I needed was a mechanism which constantly looks for tasks which are ready to run.
I have solved this by:

Creating tasks(create_tasks) and storing a dictionary of futures with me.
Then I periodically check if any of the running tasks is done.
If a task is done, check if any dependant task can br executed.
If a task can be executed, run it. Else wait for another task to complete.

Asyncio.gather was batching the tasks instead and waiting for all the tasks to complete instead. Let me know if I need to share the code/detailed approach :).

@chunchunmaru Yes, I'd be interested. You can write an answer to your own question (don't modify the question).
